# Want to redirect a page in nodes after authentication using crypt

Tags: node.js, express, bcrypt

```
app.post('/login',function(req,res){
var email=req.param("email");
var password=req.param("password");
var val;
var url1="mongodb://localhost:27017/login";
mongo.connect(url1, function(){
    var db= mongo.collection('login1');
    db.findOne({username: email}, function(err,user){
        var hash=user.password;
        bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function(err, result) {
            if(err){
                console.log("error");
            }
            console.log("result"+result);
             if(result)
            {
                console.log("its true");
                //Want to redirect to a ejs page called welcome something like res.render("welcome");
            }
             else
                 {
                 console.log("invalid");
                 }

        });
  });

 });
   });
```

Want to redirect to a ejs page called welcome something like res.render("welcome");. Cant use it there since res is not recognized in the compare function. Might be a silly question but could someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you can use [`res.redirect`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect) to redirect to another page.

For example, if you have a route that renders the secure part of your website:

```
app.get('/welcome', ..., function(req, res, next) {
   res.render('welcome');
});
```

You can use

```
res.redirect('/home');
```

to redirect the user to the secure area of your site.